# How to select max of sum of columns per another column over datetime range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, distinct

```
CREATE TABLE [T]
(
    CreatedOn DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,Code NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,R FLOAT NULL
    ,C1 FLOAT NULL
    ,C2 FLOAT NULL
    ,C3 FLOAT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [T] VALUES 
 ('2013-01-01', N'A', N'',    13, NULL,  NULL, NULL)
,('2013-01-07', N'A', N'1', NULL,    5,  NULL, NULL)
,('2013-01-31', N'A', N'2', NULL,    4,  NULL, NULL)
,('2013-02-01', N'A', N'1', NULL, NULL,     6, NULL)
,('2013-02-15', N'A', N'2', NULL, NULL,  NULL,    3)
,('2013-03-01', N'A', N'1', NULL,    1,  NULL, NULL)
,('2013-03-05', N'A', N'',     8, NULL,  NULL, NULL)
,('2013-03-22', N'A', N'2', NULL, NULL,  NULL,    1)
,('2013-05-01', N'A', N'1', NULL,    2,  NULL, NULL);

In [T]
1. One and only one non-null value per row for [R], [C1], [C2] and [C3]
2. [Code] contains a non-empty value if [C1], [C2] or [C3] contains a non-null value
3. There is an index on [Name]
4. Contains millions of rows
5. Few unique values of [Code], typically less than 100
6. Few unique values of [Name], typically less than 10000
7. Is actually a complex view containing several inner joins
```

How does one select from [T] ([DateMonth], [P]) where [CreatedOn] >= @Start AND [CreatedOn] <= @End AND [Name] = @Name AND [P] = Sum([R]) - (Sum(MaxOf(Sum([C1]), Sum([C2]), Sum([C3]), per unique [Code])))? (See the expected output below for a more accurate 'explanation'.) There should be a row in the resultset for each month @Start - @End regardless of whether there are rows for that month in [T]. Temporary table use is acceptable.

```
Expected Output
@Name = N'A'
@Start = '2012-12-01'
@End = '2013-07-01'

DateMonth    P
'2012-12-01' 0
'2013-01-01' 4  --  4 = SUM([R])=13 -      (MaxForCode'1'(SUM(C1)=5,     SUM(C2)=0,     SUM(C3)=0)=5 + MaxForCode'2'(SUM(C1)=4, SUM(C2)=0, SUM(C3)=0)=4)
'2013-02-01' 3  --  3 = SUM([R])=13 -      (MaxForCode'1'(SUM(C1)=5,     SUM(C2)=6,     SUM(C3)=0)=6 + MaxForCode'2'(SUM(C1)=4, SUM(C2)=0, SUM(C3)=3)=4)
'2013-03-01' 11 -- 11 = SUM([R])=13+8=21 - (MaxForCode'1'(SUM(C1)=5+1=6, SUM(C2)=6,     SUM(C3)=0)=6 + MaxForCode'2'(SUM(C1)=4, SUM(C2)=0, SUM(C3)=3+1=4)=4)
'2013-04-01' 11
'2013-05-01' 9  --  9 = SUM([R])=13+8=21 - (MaxForCode'1'(SUM(C1)=5+1=6, SUM(C2)=6+2=8, SUM(C3)=0)=8 + MaxForCode'2'(SUM(C1)=4, SUM(C2)=0, SUM(C3)=3+1=4)=4) 
'2013-06-01' 9
'2013-07-01' 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution.  There are certainly some performance improvements that could be made, but I'll leave that up to you and your specific situation.  Note that the CTE usage is certainly not necessary and adding CreatedOn to the index would be very helpul.  A temp table may also be better than a table variable, but you'll need to evaluate that.

Since I think what you're looking for are running totals, [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server) may be helpful in improving the performance of my suggested solution.

Personally, I would first consider not using the view, as working directly with the sql that creates the view may be more performant.

Here is the SQL and a [SQLFiddle link.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ac36/32/0)

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(1) = N'A',
@Start DATETIME = '2012-12-01',
@End DATETIME = '2013-07-01'


--get the date for the first of the start and end months
DECLARE @StartMonth DATETIME = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @Start), 0)
DECLARE @EndMonth DATETIME = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @End), 0)


DECLARE @tt TABLE
(
  DateMonth DATETIME,
  sum_r FLOAT,
  code NVARCHAR(20),
  max_c FLOAT
)

--CTE to create a simple table with an entry for each month (and nxt month)
;WITH Months
as
(
    SELECT @StartMonth as 'dt', DATEADD(month, 1, @StartMonth) as 'nxt' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, dt) as 'dt', DATEADD(month, 2, dt) as 'nxt' 
    FROM Months
    WHERE dt < @EndMonth
)
--SELECT * FROM Months OPTION(MAXRECURSION 9965) --for the CTE, you could also select dates into a temp table/table var first


INSERT INTO @tt (DateMonth, sum_r, code, max_c)
SELECT M.dt DateMonth,
       ISNULL(t.sum_r,0) sum_r,
       ISNULL(t.code,'') code,
       ISNULL(t.max_c,0) max_c
      --sum_c1, sum_c2, sum_c3, cnt
FROM Months M
     OUTER APPLY (
                   SELECT   sum_r,
                            code,
                            CASE WHEN sum_c1 >= sum_c2 AND sum_c1 >= sum_c3 THEN sum_c1
                                 WHEN sum_c2 >= sum_c1 AND sum_c2 >= sum_c3 THEN sum_c2
                                 ELSE sum_c3
                            END max_c
                             --sum_c1, sum_c2, sum_c3, cnt
                    FROM (  --use a sub select here to improve case statement performance getting max_c
                            SELECT SUM(ISNULL(r,0)) sum_r, 
                                   code, 
                                   sum(ISNULL(c1,0)) sum_c1, 
                                   sum(ISNULL(c2,0)) sum_c2, 
                                   SUM(ISNULL(c3,0)) sum_c3
                            FROM T
                            WHERE CreatedOn >= @Start AND CreatedOn < M.nxt
                                    AND CreatedOn <= @End
                                   AND Name = @Name
                            GROUP BY code
                          ) subselect
                 ) t
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 999)



SELECT DateMonth, SUM(sum_r) - SUM(max_c) p
FROM @tt
GROUP BY DateMonth
```